# How to return the system type in an SFTP?

Tags: java, ssh, ftp, sftp, jsch

FTP and SFTP are different, but I wanted to know is there a equivalent to a "SYST" command in FTP for SFTP. If I have an SFTP connection using JSch and I wanted to return the system type, how would I do that? I am converting FTP connection to SFTP. If there is no way to do with an SFTP, is there a workaround for it?

```
public String getSystemType()
        throws IOException, FtpException
{
    if(out == null)
        return null;
    acquire();    // Acquire the object

    try {
        ftpCommand("SYST");             //sends command to FTP to retrieve the system type.
        if(!reply.substring(0, 3).equals("215"))
            throw new FtpException(reply);
    } finally { 
        release();    // Release the object
    }

    return reply.substring(4);
}
```

I need this "system type" to parse the result of information of a file or directory from a location. It could be a Windows server or a UNIX server. Depending on that I need to parse it to retrieve

1) Name
 * 2) Permission  ..not available in MSDOS format list
 * 3) Type
 * 4) Owner     ..not available in MSDOS format list 
 * 5) Group     ..not available in MSDOS format list 
 * 6) Size

```
* Parse a UNIX format list. With skipping number of lines.
     * The columns of a typical UNIX format list is like:
     * drwxr-xr-x   6 appli    appli        1024 May 17 20:33 java
     * -rw-------   1 appli    appli        1005 May  1 21:21 mp3list
     * drwxr-xr-x   5 appli    appli        1024 May 17 16:56 perl
     * drwxr-xr-x   6 appli    appli        1024 Apr 30 23:18 public_html

// Some UNIX format list doesn't contain the column for group like this:
            // -rw-r--r--   1 daemon         0 Dec  7 10:15 .notar
            // -r--r--r--   1 daemon       828 Mar 30  1995 HOW_TO_SUBMIT
            // -r--r--r--   1 daemon       627 Mar 30  1995 README
            // -r--r--r--   1 daemon       876 Mar 30  1995 WELCOME
            // drwxr-xr-x   2 ftp          512 Oct 13  1999 bin
```

Comment: do you actually need that system type, or is it just informational? Could you replace the return value just with some dummy text and it would still work? Because code depending on the system description of a remote server seems a bit brittle to me.

Comment: @cello There is another function where it does a "LIST" to return info about the file or directory.  it is used to parse the return string, I have a method in the old FTP class, where it verifies if its the UNIX format or the MS-DOS format. I am not sure if this is needed in the SFTP. I was just trying to keep the methods as it is and only convert the process inside those to SFTP.

Comment: I do not understand what your edit (about parsing information about a file or directory) has to do with your question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl what I meant was, depending on the system type I would parse the data differently, since each system has a slightly different way of sending the information of the files and directories.  I would identify which system it is, so if it is UNIX, then I know it has 9 columns and if it is windows then only 3 columns, Name, type, and size can be obtained from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSH version string.

It is like:

- SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
- SSH-2.0-7.34 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 7.34
- SSH-2.0-1.36_sshlib GlobalSCAPE
- SSH-2.0-mod_sftp/0.9.8

In JSch you can retrieve it by using [`Session.getServerVersion`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#getServerVersion--).

---

SFTP itself provides information about the remote system only using an [optional extension "vendor-id"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00#section-2), which is rarely supported. It's definitely not supported by JSch itself and neither by the most widespread SFTP server implementation, the OpenSSH.

---

*Though note that with SFTP, you typically do not need to parse the directory listing. In SFTP most of the listing data come in a form of binary structure, not a textual listing like with FTP.*

Answer (score 1):

The most widely deployed SFTP server is the [server](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server) included with [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/). It implements [version 3 draft 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02). Jsch also implements that version of SFTP.

The FTP SYST command returns a string describing the server's system type. Sftp version 3 draft 2 doesn't implement anything like the FTP SYST command that I can see. There's no command that returns the server's operating system or a set of capabilities.

Without knowing why you need the information, it's impossible to say how to work around this.